# Create a SQLite db under a specific folder in a Java application

Tags: java, sqlite, directory

I need to create this db under a specific folder known as dbs. I tried "\" & ".". 
Both didnt work as expected

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dbs\test.db");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you expect? What was the actual result?

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape your backslash

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dbs\\test.db");
```

Also you have to have the folder dbs already created in your directory.

Comment: AFAIK backslashes (\\) would only work with windows... Instead of using (\\\), try a simple slash `/`: `c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dbs/test.db");`